Z score for progressive age using WHO BMI for children
I need python code which would compare WHO dataset of BMI z socre using python code
i have tried git repository to solvethe issue but havent found the solution. i have found pygrowup library also. but unab;le to solve the problem.
Kibldy help me solve the issue.
